# Javascript cut table to insert a tag <div>

Tags: javascript, split, append

I want to cut `table` after `tr` to insert a `div` and re-open the `table` :

Before :

```
<table>
    <tr onClick="cutAfter(this);">
        <td>bla</td><td> 123 </td><td>Yes </td>
    </tr>
    <tr onClick="cutAfter(this);">
        <td>bli</td><td> 456 </td><td>no</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onClick="cutAfter(this);">
        <td>blu</td><td> 789 </td><td>hum</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

After :

```
<table>
    <tr onClick="cutAfter(this);">
        <td>bla</td><td> 123 </td><td>Yes </td>
    </tr>
    <tr onClick="cutAfter(this);">
        <td>bli</td><td> 456 </td><td>no</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div onClick="fuse(this)">It works</div>
<table>
    <tr onClick="cutAfter(this);">
        <td>blu</td><td> 789 </td><td>hum</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And return to first state on click.
Any idea (no jQuery).

Comment: Yes, but where is the code that you have tried?

Comment: Collect rows to a collection (using `querySelectorAll()`), create a new `div` and insert it after the `table`. Then create a new `table`, and append that after the `div`, finally append the rows from the collection to the newly-created `table`.

Comment: Interesting question, but Xotic is right, you need to try at least one thing on your own.

Comment: Should a `DIV` be inserted after the last `TR` even if there has not been a cut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple whay to do it is to use combination of DOM manipulation methods like [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) to create new table and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) to move rows into new table:

```js
function cutAfter(row) {
    var table = row.parentNode.parentNode;
  
    if (row.nextElementSibling) {
        table.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<table><tbody></tbody></table>');
        var newTable = table.nextElementSibling.tBodies[0];

        while (row.nextElementSibling) {
            newTable.appendChild(row.nextElementSibling);
        }
    }

}
```

```css
table {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table td {
    border: 1px #AAA solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr onClick="cutAfter(this);">
        <td>bla</td><td> 123 </td><td>Yes </td>
    </tr>
    <tr onClick="cutAfter(this);">
        <td>bli</td><td> 456 </td><td>no</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onClick="cutAfter(this);">
        <td>blu</td><td> 789 </td><td>hum</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great ! Very effective ! I did not know insertAdjacentHTML. I was stuck between innerHTML (/table...table) unsatisfactory and the appendChild a bit complicated. You have an idea for the reverse ?

Comment: What do you mean "reverse", did I miss something from the question?

Comment: In fact, it's easy to go back with your code : remove the div created and while appendChild... 
Thank you @dfsq

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example, made of an HTML file (the structure) and a Javascript file (the behavior). The script uses node manipulation, so as to preserve existing handlers (e.g. added by other scripts). It also attaches event handlers directly, using element.onxxx, to keep things simple, but you should replace that by your favorite event manager.

```js
var makeSplittable = function(table, joinText) {

  init();

  function init() {
    var tBodies = table.tBodies;
    for (var ii = 0; ii < tBodies.length; ii++) {
      var rows = tBodies[ii].rows;
      for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        rows[j].onclick = split; // Replace with your favorite event manager
      }
    }
  }

  function split(evt) {
    var rowIndex = this.rowIndex;
    var tbody = findParent(this, "tbody");
    var numRows = tbody.rows.length;
    if (rowIndex < numRows - 1) {
      var rows = [];
      for (var ii = rowIndex + 1; ii < numRows; ii++) {
        rows.push(tbody.rows[ii]);
      }
      var existingTable = findParent(this, "table");
      var newTable = createTable(rows);
      var joiner = createJoiner();
      existingTable.parentNode.insertBefore(newTable, existingTable.nextSibling);
      existingTable.parentNode.insertBefore(joiner, existingTable.nextSibling);
    }
  }

  function createTable(rows) {
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    for (var ii = 0; ii < rows.length; ii++) {
      tbody.appendChild(rows[ii]);
    }
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    return table;
  }

  function createJoiner() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var content = document.createTextNode(joinText);
    div.appendChild(content);
    div.onclick = join; // same
    return div;
  }

  function join(evt) {
    var previousTable = this.previousSibling;
    var nextTable = this.nextSibling;
    var tbody = previousTable.tBodies[previousTable.tBodies.length - 1];
    var rows = nextTable.rows;
    while (rows.length) {
      tbody.appendChild(rows[0]);
    }
    nextTable.parentNode.removeChild(nextTable);
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  }

  function findParent(element, type) {
    if (!element || !type) {
      return null;
    }
    if (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == type.toLowerCase()) {
      return element;
    }
    return findParent(element.parentNode, type);
  }

};

makeSplittable(document.getElementById("target"), "Merge adjacent tables");
```

```css
table,
div {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
tr:hover td {
  background-color: orange;
}
td {
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}
div {
  color: #0c0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id="target">
  <tr>
    <td>bla</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bli</td>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>no</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blu</td>
    <td>789</td>
    <td>hum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can't say that I like the style or inefficiency but it works and demonstrates a complete solution to the question, which is more than the accepted answer does. :)

Answer (score 0):

A possibility, assuming that a `DIV` should not be inserted after the last `TR` if there has not been a cut, but it would have been nice to see your effort. Also assuming no `<thead>` or `<tfoot>`.

```js
function isTagName(element, tagName) {
  return element.tagName.toUpperCase() === tagName.toUpperCase();
}

function getClosest(element, tagName) {
  var closest = null;

  while (element !== document && !isTagName(element, tagName)) {
    element = element.parentNode;
  }

  if (element !== document && isTagName(element, tagName)) {
    closest = element;
  }

  return closest;
}

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
  return referenceNode.parentNode
          .insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function moveAppend(list, dest, from) {
  var index = list.length - 1,
    last;

  for (last = from || 0; index >= last; index -= 1) {
    dest.appendChild(list[index]);
  }

  return dest;
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target,
    tr = getClosest(target, 'tr'),
    newDiv,
    newTable,
    newBody,
    next,
    parent;

  if (tr) {
    if (tr.rowIndex < tr.parentNode.rows.length - 1) {
      newDiv = document.createElement('div');
      newDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('It works!'));
      insertAfter(newDiv, getClosest(tr, 'table'));
      newTable = document.createElement('table');
      newBody = document.createElement('tbody');
      moveAppend(tr.parentNode.rows, newBody, tr.rowIndex + 1);
      newTable.appendChild(newBody);
      insertAfter(newTable, newDiv);
    }
  } else if (isTagName(target, 'div') &&
              isTagName(target.previousElementSibling, 'table') &&
              isTagName(target.nextElementSibling, 'table')) {

    next = target.nextElementSibling;
    moveAppend(next.tBodies[0].rows, target.previousElementSibling.tBodies[0]);
    parent = target.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(next);
    parent.removeChild(target);
  }
}, false);
```

```css
table,
td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>bla</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bli</td>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>no</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blu</td>
    <td>789</td>
    <td>hum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Xotic, I had not succeeded, I did not expect to have to show my musty code. I have well understood your heavy message.