# Get tr from inside element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a simple HTML code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="pathText" type="text" name="Summary" placeholder="Summary"><br>
    <input id="groupText" type="text" name="Groups" placeholder="Groups"><br>
    <input id="searchButton" type="button" value="Search" onclick="myFunction()"><br>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <details class="mainDetails">
       <summary><b>First Summary</b></summary>
       <ul>
        <details>
         <summary><b>Groups</b></summary>
         <ul>
          <li>group A of First</li>
          <li>group B of First</li>
         </ul>
        </details>
        <details>
         <summary><b>First People</b></summary>
         <ul>
          <li>John</li>
          <li>Mark</li>
         </ul>
        </details>
       </ul>
      </details>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
      <details class="mainDetails">
       <summary><b>Second Summary</b></summary>
       <ul>
        <details>
         <summary><b>Groups</b></summary>
         <ul>
          <li>group A of Second</li>
          <li>group B of Second</li>
          <li>group C of Second</li>
         </ul>
        </details>
        <details>
         <summary><b>Second People</b></summary>
         <ul>
          <li>Alex</li>
         </ul>
        </details>
       </ul>
      </details>
     </tr>
    </table>
    
    <script>
    
     function myFunction(){
      var pathString = document.getElementById('pathText').value;
      var summariesElements=document.getElementsByTagName("summary");
      for(i=0;i<summariesElements.length;i++){
       if(summariesElements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(pathString) !== -1){
        if(summariesElements[i].parentElement.className === "mainDetails"){
         alert(summariesElements[i].parentElement.className);
         summariesElements[i].parentElement.style.display = "none"; 
        }
       }
      }
     }
    </script>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

I want to hide the `tr` element from details which summary consists `String` from `pathText` `input`. 
In my code I know how to get `mainDetails` element by using `myFunction()` to hide it.

I tried to add `class="trClass"` and modify this function to get `tr` element and use `display="none"`. I use something like:

```
function myFunction(){
        var pathString = document.getElementById('pathText').value;
        var summariesElements=document.getElementsByTagName("summary");
        for(i=0;i<summariesElements.length;i++){
            if(summariesElements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(pathString) !== -1){
                alert(summariesElements[i].parentElement.parentElement.className);
                if(summariesElements[i].parentElement.parentElement.className === "trClass"){
                summariesElements[i].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none"; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But there is a problem because `summariesElements[i].parentElement.parentElement` doesn't return the `tr` element, it returns just `body`.

How can I change my code and use it to hide just `tr` from my `table`?

Comment: could you provide an example ?

Comment: I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406890/3425489

Comment: you missed the <td> tag in your <tr> tag, bcoz of that your details tag is rendered outside of the table if you look at in developer tool and you are getting body tag. Just add <td> tag then you will get proper parentElement.Refere https://jsfiddle.net/5eg5a486/

Comment: Agree with @HemantD . He pointed out before me, so credit goes to him.

Comment: Also you missed a closing script tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `td` (column) element for row. A row must have at least one column.

```
<tr>
<td>
<!-- content goes here -->
</td>
</tr>
```

Also, to get row reference instead of

```
summariesElements[i].parentElement.parentElement
```

you can use

```
summariesElements[i].closest('tr')
```

Please check [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcdwL5ym/1/) demonstrating achieving same using jQuery

Here is fix of your coding, mainly adding `td` tag

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="pathText" type="text" name="Summary" placeholder="Summary"><br>
  <input id="groupText" type="text" name="Groups" placeholder="Groups"><br>
  <input id="searchButton" type="button" value="Search" onclick="myFunction()"><br>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <details class="mainDetails">
          <summary><b>First Summary</b></summary>
          <ul>
            <details>
              <summary><b>Groups</b></summary>
              <ul>
                <li>group A of First</li>
                <li>group B of First</li>
              </ul>
            </details>
            <details>
              <summary><b>First People</b></summary>
              <ul>
                <li>John</li>
                <li>Mark</li>
              </ul>
            </details>
          </ul>
        </details>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <details class="mainDetails">
          <summary><b>Second Summary</b></summary>
          <ul>
            <details>
              <summary><b>Groups</b></summary>
              <ul>
                <li>group A of Second</li>
                <li>group B of Second</li>
                <li>group C of Second</li>
              </ul>
            </details>
            <details>
              <summary><b>Second People</b></summary>
              <ul>
                <li>Alex</li>
              </ul>
            </details>
          </ul>
        </details>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var pathString = document.getElementById('pathText').value;
      var summariesElements = document.getElementsByTagName("summary");
      for (i = 0; i < summariesElements.length; i++) {
        if (summariesElements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(pathString) !== -1) {
          if (summariesElements[i].parentElement.className === "mainDetails") {
            //alert(summariesElements[i].parentElement.className);
            summariesElements[i].parentElement.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I've fixed the mark up to include td elements, and closing script.
I've also used [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)/[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) which adds a bit more flexibility to getting DOM nodes.
Check out the [CSSSelectors docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors), that these commands use.
So you can in effect do things like find by id, class, 'tag A' within 'tag B', direct descendants, etc.
Here it is in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLgw0vmy/)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="pathText" type="text" name="Summary" placeholder="Summary"><br>
<input id="groupText" type="text" name="Groups" placeholder="Groups"><br>
<input id="searchButton" type="button" value="Search" onclick="myFunction()"><br>
<table>
    <tr><td>
        <details class="mainDetails">
            <summary><b>First Summary</b></summary>
            <ul>
                <details>
                    <summary><b>Groups</b></summary>
                    <ul>
                        <li>group A of First</li>
                        <li>group B of First</li>
                    </ul>
                </details>
                <details>
                    <summary><b>First People</b></summary>
                    <ul>
                        <li>John</li>
                        <li>Mark</li>
                    </ul>
                </details>
            </ul>
        </details>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>    
        <details class="mainDetails">
            <summary><b>Second Summary</b></summary>
            <ul>
                <details>
                    <summary><b>Groups</b></summary>
                    <ul>
                        <li>group A of Second</li>
                        <li>group B of Second</li>
                        <li>group C of Second</li>
                    </ul>
                </details>
                <details>
                    <summary><b>Second People</b></summary>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Alex</li>
                    </ul>
                </details>
            </ul>
        </details>
    </td></tr>
</table>

<script>

    function myFunction(){
        var inputValue = document.querySelector('#pathText').value;
        var trElements=document.querySelectorAll("tr");
        for(i=0;i<trElements.length;i++){
            var summaryText = trElements[i].querySelector("b").innerText
            if (inputValue === summaryText) {
               trElements[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```