# what is closest function javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert a `jquery` function to `vanila js`.I don't know the implementation of that function I just want to convert `jquery` function to javascript . here is my jquery function.

```
jQuery('button.vjs-share-control').on('touchstart click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.type == "touchstart") {
        var embedDiv = jQuery(this).closest('div.bcvideo');
        var vid = videojs(embedDiv.data('bcobjid'));
        var shareopts = {
            "services": setSocialLinks.call(embedDiv)
        };
        // set share links
        vid.social(shareopts);
        jQuery('#w10close').removeClass('hidden');

  } else if(e.type == "click") {
    var embedDiv = jQuery(this).closest('div.bcvideo');
        var vid = videojs(embedDiv.data('bcobjid'));
        var shareopts = {
            "services": setSocialLinks.call(embedDiv)
        };
        // set share links
        vid.social(shareopts);
        jQuery('#w10close').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

I covert this function to javascript but I am confused by `closest` and `call` function how to convert these `jquery` function to javascript.

Here is my javascript function (converted jquery function to javascript)

```
document.querySelector('button.vjs-share-control').addEventListener('touchstart click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.type == "touchstart") {
    var embedDiv = document.querySelector(this).closest('div.bcvideo');
    var vid = videojs(embedDiv.data('bcobjid'));
    var shareopts = {
      "services": setSocialLinks.call(embedDiv)
    };
    // set share links
    vid.social(shareopts);
    document.querySelector('#w10close').classList.remove('hidden');

  } else if(e.type == "click") {
    var embedDiv = document.querySelector(this).closest('div.bcvideo');
    var vid = videojs(embedDiv.data('bcobjid'));
    var shareopts = {
      "services": setSocialLinks.call(embedDiv)
    };
    // set share links
    vid.social(shareopts);
    document.querySelector('#w10close').classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});
```

is it a right converted function ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vanilla JavaScript .closest without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406403/vanilla-javascript-closest-without-jquery)

Comment: @kmoser thanks for comment ..What do you think is it a correct ? Mean I converted jquery code to javascript .Is javascript code is correct ? will is behave same as jquery code

Comment: Did you try it? Does it work?

Comment: What do you expect "`document.querySelector(this)`" to do? Just use `this`. Also your element probably hasn't been extended to have a `.data()` method. How was the jQuery's data appended to that element? Through *data-attribute* or via pure jQuery method?

Comment: `document.querySelector(this)` same as `jQuery(this)`

Comment: `No idea` dorry.Also your element probably hasn't been extended to have a .data() method. How was the jQuery's data appended to that element? Through data-attribute or via pure jQuery method?

Answer (score 0):

The Element.closest( ) function can be used to get the closest parent which satisfies the query condition. For example, in the below code, I have the  tag and a  inside the body tag, I have the same class attached to both  and the  tags.

**Please run the below code and read the comments to understand how Element.closest( ) works in this case:**

```js
const inputField = document.querySelector('.textbox');

//logging the inputField variable
console.log(inputField);

//This retuns the <h1> because that is the closest parent
//with 'inner-parent' class.
console.log(inputField.closest('.inner-parent'));

//This returns the 'div' element instead of the 'body'
//although both have the same class, that is because <div>
//is closer to input element than the <body>
console.log(inputField.closest('.outer-parent'));
```

```html
<body class = 'outer-parent'> 
<div class='outer-parent'>
<h1 class='inner-parent' >
<input type='text' class='textbox'> 
</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

Also, please note, that the closest( ) function only works on parents, you cannot use it to find parents or siblings directly. However, you can query the parent to get the sibling element if needed.