# How to delete row from table using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was trying on button click delete the row from table in javascript.I am able to do so usig jquery, but is it possible to do using pure vanilla javascript.

Is there way to use click event and delete the row ?

```js
$(".delete").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vanilla JavaScript .closest without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406403/vanilla-javascript-closest-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `onClick` for each button

```js
function deleteRow(button) {
     const tr = button.parentNode.parentNode;
     tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button onClick="deleteRow(this);" class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td><button onClick="deleteRow(this);" class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td><button onClick="deleteRow(this);" class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I feel like @P.E. Joëssel's answer is better, as it's more descriptive, and adding event listeners is better than manually repeating yourself with the `onClick="deleteRow(this);"`

Comment: potato , potahto

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function for `onclick` event for the every `<td>Del</td>`. When you click on it you should get the `tr` parent element something like this:

And don't forget that function to the `onclick` event for the buttons!

```js
const onDelete = (event) => {
  const buttonElement = event;
  const tdElement = buttonElement.parentNode;
  const trElement = tdElement.parentNode;

  trElement.remove();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="delete" onclick="onDelete(this)">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td><button class="delete" onclick="onDelete(this)">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td><button class="delete" onclick="onDelete(this)">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in jQuery can be replicated in vanilla javascript. With the same html, I would do it like this:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

const addRemoveListener = button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', removeListener);
}

const removeListener = event => {
  const button = event.currentTarget;
  const cell = button.parentNode;
  const row = cell.parentNode;
  row.remove();
}

buttons.forEach(addRemoveListener);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```