# From JQuery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the javascript equivalent of the following jquery line?

Javascript Context:

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
var $text = $row.find(".nr").text(); // Find the text
```

HTML Context (Table):

```
        <tr>
            <td class="nr"><span>50</span>
            </td>
            <td>Some Street 1</td>
            <td>
                <button class="use-address"> Test </button>
                       
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="nr">49</td>
            <td>Some Street 2</td>
            <td>
                <button class="use-address" > Test </button>
            </td>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vanilla JavaScript .closest without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406403/vanilla-javascript-closest-without-jquery)

Comment: I tried changing to this: document.querySelector('.nr').closest('tr').text();. It does not work, and I don't know why.

Comment: `document.querySelector` isn't the equivalent of `$row.find`.  Please include some html and context - eg what's `this`?

Comment: The link above and http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ gives something like, probably: 
  `var text = this.closest("tr").querySelector(".nr").textContent`  **Edit**: yep, that seems to work ok: https://jsfiddle.net/2pcavnsj/  - but it is really a duplicate

Comment: @freedomn-m I have added in the HTML context. It's searching for the column text in the table. Thank you, your solution works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your original code looked similar to the following:

```js
$('table').on('click', '.use-address', function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Find the row
  var text = $row.find(".nr").text().trim(); // Find the text
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="nr"><span>50</span>
      </td>
      <td>Some Street 1</td>
      <td>
        <button class="use-address"> Test </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="nr">49</td>
      <td>Some Street 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="use-address"> Test </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You should avoid declaring variables with leading `$` (dollar signs), unless the value they hold is an actual jQuery element.

The equivalent would be the following:

```js
const handleClick = ({ target }) => {
  if (target.classList.contains('use-address')) {
    const row = target.closest('tr');
    const text = row.querySelector('.nr').textContent.trim();
    console.log(text);
  }
};

document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="nr"><span>50</span>
      </td>
      <td>Some Street 1</td>
      <td>
        <button class="use-address"> Test </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="nr">49</td>
      <td>Some Street 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="use-address"> Test </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Checkout ["You might not need jQuery"](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) to see some examples of equivalent plain JS code.